# Calling ajax consecutive does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I Have an ajax method, which I use to change the status of an object. Each status can change by clicking on that element at any time.

The problem is that after loading the page for the first time, It works properly. But When I click again, if does not fire even (I debug that and I saw it does not enter to the script at all). I need that the user can click on the button and change the status for every click.

I searched a lot and tests the ways which I list below. But none of them works for me:

1. Using .preventDefault() in a the ajax method (In this way, if I comment the ajax method calling and just alert something, it works and the message alerts in each click, but when I call the ajax, it does not work)
2. Using .noConflict()
3. Adding cashe : false

This is the code:

**HTML**:

```
 <tr>
       <td> 21.</td>
       <td>Title 1</td>
       <td><span class="badge bg-green">10</span></td>
       <td>n</td>
       <td><a id="1026" class="badge bg-red status">Status</a></td>
       <td>
         <a class="btn btn-app" id="1026"><i class="fa fa-close"></i>
         </a>
       </td>
    </tr>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
                $(".status").on("click", function(){

                    var Id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
                    var inquiryId = @Model.Id;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("ChangeSuggestionStatus", "Inquiry")',
                        data : '{id : ' + '"' +  Id + '"' + ', inquiryId:' + '"' + inquiryId + '"' + '}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        async : false,                       
                        success: function (data) {
                            $( ".table-bordered" ).empty();
                            $( ".table-bordered" ).append(data);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.d);},
                        error: function (xhr) {
                           alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' ' + xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Could you please help me to solve the problem?
Do you think one of values which I set for ajax can prevent the next calling of ajax?

Regards!

Comment: Is `$(".status")` inside `$(".table-bordered")`? And what does `data` on ajax success contains? Can you add the html, at least the part where the click and append or status change takes place.

Comment: there's absolutely no need to do `async : false,` - it's deprecated and results in poor user experience

Comment: @Erwin Yes. The status is inside the table. on success I create the rows of the table which contains the related data for the model. I edited my question with the HTML codes.

Comment: Do a *simple* test for debugging. clear all your codes inside `click` function, then just write a simple `console.log('test')` see your click event works at all or not?

Comment: @JaromandaX I test it, but removing that does not solve the problem.

Comment: @GolnazSaraji Hi. Can you add what exactly `data` contains on the ajax's success function? I'm thinking that would be a big help solving this

Comment: @GolnazSaraji - I never said that was your problem. Just pointed out the pointlessness of a synchronous ajax request in a click event handler

Comment: @ pedram I said that, for the first time everything is Ok, But after that the code does not fire. I mean that it does not enter in click event at all

Comment: @GolnazSaraji - what would really help is if you showed where the `.table-bordered` element is, in relation to `.status`

Comment: @JaromandaX Maybe you are right, but adding that solved my problem in  calling ajax Which I faced before and I can not remove it. thanks!

Comment: @JaromandaX Did you see my html code? do you mean to add that?

Comment: Where is the target for the append

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160331/discussion-between-golnaz-saraji-and-jaromanda-x).